# Django and Rabbitmq Architecture

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I want to use RabbitMQ with Django for message queuing. Currently I am having a new instance of RabbitMQ and celery with each Django app server. I wanted to know is this the best method? Or should I have a single cluster of RabbitMQ for queuing the messages and multiple celery for executing those tasks on the first come basis?

Comment: So, if I understand your current setup, each worker has it's own separate instance of the broker (such that the relationship between broker and worker is 1:1)? This seems to make little sense.

Comment: Yes this is my current setup. I am more inclined to what @Greg0ry suggested about load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

If you load balance your web app and your intention is to run multiple celery workers on each host then you definitely want all workers to use the same rabbitmq cluster. I like to spread my rabbitmq cluster accross nodes I run workers on with queue persistence feature turned on. But you can chose to have separate rabbit cluster (depending on your budget).

If you run multiple separate apps then I would run rabbit localy just for that app.

-- edit --

In the comment you mentioned that your app is load balanced and that you was trying to cluster rabbit and have an issue with multiple workers executing the same task.

A few things come to my mind and it would be nice if you can post your celery.py/celeryconfig.py and an example code showing how do you insert your task to the queue.

At this point I can advise on clustering as this is very straight forward:

- Elect your primary cluster node (i.e. host name rabbit1)
- On secondary cluster node remove the content of /var/lib/rabbitmq/* (do not remove the folder itself!)
- On secondary cluster node copy the .erlang.cookie from primary node (it should have been created when you first started your rabbitmq and you can usually find it under /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie); This file must hold exactly the same content on both nodes and also must be owned by rabbitmq:rabbitmq with group and others cut off.
- Make sure your /etc/hosts mentions both nodes on both nodes
- Start both nodes
- On secondary node run following commands (as rabbitmq user, this is important since .erlang.cookie is created on per-user basis and most likely your rabbitmq process runs as rabbitmq user):

(following commands run on rabbit2)

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@rabbit1
rabbitmqctl start_app
rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-all "" '{"ha-mode":"all","ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}'
```

Note - last command is to make the queue persistent across nodes, so when one node dies your cluster will continue working without any loss of tasks.

You can check if the cluster works fine with this command:

```
rabbitmqctl cluster_status
```

I would advise if you can stop all your workers and insert one task to the queue and then run this command to see if there is only one task in the queue:

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues -p your_vhost_name
```

There should be only one task in the queue.

Then you can check what is the exchange you are using. From your comment I would guess that maybe you are using fanout exchange. I am not too deep into exchanges but you can check your exchanges by running this command:

```
rabbitmqctl list_exchanges -p your_vhost_name
```

or analyse output of following:

```
rabbitmqctl report
```

Comment: Yes I am load balancing my web app. I tried using the clustered RabbitMQ but was facing the issue in which each celery worker was executing the task, whereas I want only one to execute the task. I haven't dig deeper in the cluster setup. Would look into it more to see if RabbitMQ has any config setting which could achieve this.